# web app open in net tab not open in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am accessing my react component through sales force marketing cloud. When i click a link in my aplication the new page also loaded inside SFMC. But when I select open in new tab option, the webapp loaded not inside SFMC. I need to open the page in SFMC